# How to change a 1 or blank in MySQL field to be either Y or N?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm exporting a MySQL table to be used in Salesforce. There is a field for where the data is either set to a 1 or blank. I need to be able to have MySQL output this as a Y for 1 and a N for blank. Can this be done with MySQL or is it better to do this in PHP or must it be done in PHP?
I don't know MySQL well enough, is there something like IF field1 = "1" then field1="Y", else field1="N"? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the mysql documentation I suggest. MySQL offers conditionals on sql level.

Comment: You need to just output it like that, or replace it in the table?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, IF(field1=1,'Y','N') as field1 FROM ...
```

> is it better to do this in PHP?

No difference

Answer (score 1):

You can have it like this:

```sql
SELECT IF( field1 = 1, 'Y', 'N' ) AS `field`
FROM `tablename`
```

Or, alternatively:

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN field1 = 1 THEN 'Y' WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN 'N' END) AS `field`
FROM `tablename`
```

---

If you're interested in updating, then it'd be like this:

```sql
UPDATE `tablename`
SET field1 = REPLACE( REPLACE( `field1`, NULL, 'N'), '1', 'Y' );
```

Comment: a WHEN is missing: `CASE WHEN`